# Mute printf without macros

Tags: c

Is there a way I can mute all my printf statements conditionally, however, without using any macros? I want to accomplish the muting without touching the already existing code, but adding a line to my module which would simply disable all printf's already existing in the source code.

Thanks!

Comment: do you only want to mute `printf`s or every output to `stdout`?

Comment: Do you need to revert back to normal behaviour, so only muting for a while and then doing normal printf output again?

Comment: @rwos: Just printf preferrably.

Comment: @Werner: Yes reverting back would be preferred...

Comment: If you only want to mute printf and not all output to stdout, why did you accept the answer that nullifies all output to stdout and is implementation-dependent instead of an answer that nullifies only printf and is portable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to nullify all output to `stdout` via `printf`, `puts`, `putchar`, etc., you can use [`freopen(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/freopen) to redirect it to a bit bucket, e.g.:

```
// On Unix and Unix-like systems:
freopen("/dev/null", "w", stdout);
// On Windows:
freopen("NUL", "w", stdout);
```

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, BSD or other Unix you could create a shared library which provides its own `printf` and wraps the C library `printf`.

Then you would load it ahead of the C library using `LD_PRELOAD=mylib.so ./myprogram`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the library printf with your own implementation by adding this to your source code:

```
int printf(const char * restrict format,...) { return 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It worked in my situation (Linux/GCC) (It should works in both Unix and Windows, but I have not test in Windows).

```
//saving current stdout descriptor
FILE oldstdout = *stdout;
//open a output stream to null
FILE *mystdout = fopen("/dev/null", "w"); //to unix
if( !mystdout )        
    mystdout = fopen("NUL", "w"); // to Windows

*stdout = *mystdout; //replacing stdout by our stream to null

/*******  PUT YOUR CODE HERE TO BE "MUTED" *******/

//enabling back stdout 
*stdout = oldstdout;
fclose(mystdout);   //closing my null stream
```

The advantage of this solution is stdout is never closed. So, the original stdout can be restored at any time as it is necessary. We also do not have any risk of stdout file descriptor be assigned to another output stream.